# Tokenize result of a NGramFilterFactory in Solr (query analyzer)

Tags: filter, solr, full-text-search, tokenize

I'm using the NGramFilterFactory for indexing and querying.

So if I'm searching for "overflow" it creates an query like this:

```
mySearchField:"ov ve ... erflow overflo verflow overflow"
```

But if I misspell "overflow", i.e. "owerflow" there are no matches, because the quotes around the query:

```
mySearchField:"ow we ... erflow owerflo werflow owerflow"
```

Is it possible to tokenize the result of the NGramFilteFactory, that it'll creates an query like this:

```
mySearchField:"ow"
mySearchField:"we"
mySearchField:"erflow"
mySearchField:"owerflo"
mySearchField:"werflow"
mySearchField:"owerflow"
```

In this case solr would also find results, because the token "erflow" exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found a quick and easy way to solve the problem.

The fieldType has an optional attribute autoGeneratePhraseQueries (Default=true). If I set autoGeneratePhraseQueries to false, everything works fine.

**Explanation:**

fieldType used in schema.xml:

```
<fieldType name="edgytext" class="solr.TextField" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="false">
 <analyzer type="index">
   <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
   <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
   <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="25" />
 </analyzer>
 <analyzer type="query">
   <tokenizer class="solr.WhiteSpaceTokenizerFactory"/>
   <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
   <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="25" />
 </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

If you are indexing the word "surprise", following tokens are in the index:

> s, su, ,sur, surp, surpr, surpri, surpris, surprise

If you are search for "surpriese" (misspelled) solr creates following tokens (matching tokens are bold):

> **s**, **su**, **sur**, **surp**, **surpr**, **surpri**, surprie, surpries, surpriese

The real query which will be created looks like:

> mySearchField:s, mySearchField:su, mySearchField:sup .. and so on

But if you set autoGeneratePhraseQueries=true following query will be created:

> mySearchField:"s su surp supr surprie surpries surpriese"

This is an phrase query and does not match the indexed terms.

Comment: Actually I don't understand this solution, but I'm curious, I didn't know that parameter ;) Could you post your `mySearchField` field definition from your `schema.xml` please?

Comment: @javanna I added an explanation to my answer. Please note that I finally used the EdgeNGramFilter

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to tokenize your query like you wrote. Check if in your `schema.xml` you have the `NGramFilterFactory` applied at both index time and query time.
Then, the query parser you're using makes the difference. With `LuceneQParser` you'd get the result you're looking for, but not with `DisMax` and `eDisMax`.

I checked the query `mySearchField:owerflow` with `eDisMax` and `debugQuery=on`:

```
<str name="querystring">text:owerflow</str>
<str name="parsedquery">
+((text:o text:w text:e text:r text:f text:l text:o text:w text:ow text:we text:er text:rf text:fl text:lo text:ow text:owe text:wer text:erf text:rfl text:flo text:low text:ower text:werf text:erfl text:rflo text:flow text:owerf text:werfl text:erflo text:rflow text:owerfl text:werflo text:erflow text:owerflo text:werflow text:owerflow)~36)
</str>
```

If you look at the end of the generated query you'll see `~36` where 36 is the number of n-grams generated from your query. You don't get any results because of that `~36`, but you can change it through the [`mm`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin#mm_.28Minimum_.27Should.27_Match.29) parameter, which is the minimum should match.

If you change the query to `mySearchField:owerflow&mm=1` or a value lower than 25 you'll have the result you're looking for.

The difference between this answer and yours is that with `EdgeNGramFilterFactory` an infix  query like `mySearchField:werflow` doesn't return any result, while it does with `NGramFilterFactory`.

Anyway, If you're using the `NGramFilterFactory` for making spelling correction, I'd strongly recommend to have a look at the [`SpellCheckComponent`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent) as well, made exactly for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. SpellCheckComponent is my specific case not suitable, because I need search results of a misspelled word and not suggestions for the right spelling. But I found another solution (see my answer).

Comment: @MaxSchmidt I had the chance to have a look deeper at your question and found a solution using `NGramFilterFactory`, have a look at my updated answer. Anyway you canof course use the `SpellCheckComponent` to make spelling corrections from mispelled words.

Comment: Thats strange. With eDisMax and debugQuery=on and without autoGeneratePhraseQueries="false" I get:
<str name="querystring">text:overflow</str>
<str name="parsedquery">
+DisjunctionMaxQuery((text:"o v e r f l o w ov ve er rf fl lo ow")) ()
</str>

Comment: Weird! Which solr version? Are you sure `eDisMax` not `DisMax`?

Comment: Exact querystring: http://localhost:8983/solr/select?indent=on&q=text:overflow&fq=&start=0&rows=1&defType=edismax&qf=text&debugQuery=on
I'm using solr/lucene 3.5

Comment: Looks like if I search `q=overflow&qf=text` the parsed query is the same as yours, but if I use `q=text:overflow&qf=text` it's like mine. I'm using 3.5 too.

Comment: Sorry, two comments before I searched q=overflow and not text:overflow. If I search q=text:overflow Solr auto generates a phrase query:
<str name="querystring">text:overflow</str>
<str name="parsedquery">
+PhraseQuery(text:"o v e r f l o w ov ve er rf fl lo ow")
</str>
Are you using Solr <=3.1 or defined in solrconfig.xml a differing lucene version?

Comment: No, lucene/solr 3.5 and LUCENE_35 match version. That's strange.